# C# Stream Pipe (Stream Spy)

Tags: c#, stream, pipe, splitter

I have an input stream and a stream reader component. This works fine but now I want to log all the traffic (save a copy in a file). 
So I need to spy on a stream. A solution I am thinking of is a stream pipe (pipeline) or a stream wrapper that takes a stream as input and then gives me a first look at the traffic. Something like this:

```
    void Init(System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream)
    {
        System.IO.Stream wrappedStream = new MyWrapper(stream);
        wrappedStream.ReadSpy = MyMethod;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(wrappedStream);
    }

    // This will get called after some bytes have been read from a stream,
    // but before they get passed to the XmlReader
    byte[] MyMethod(byte[] buffer)
    {
        m_Writer.Write(buffer); // write to a file 
        return buffer; // Give to XmlReader 
    }
```

Comment: What type of help you are looking from SO? Clearly you know that you need to have wrapper class for stream and probably already tried to write one... Specifying concrete problem you hit when doing so would be more suitable for SO than question in current form (which looks like "plz give me teh codez", and hence can be considered  off-topic as search for tools/libraries).

Comment: No, I have not tried to write my own yet, I don't like inventing a bicycle. I think that a pipe would be a very useful abstraction and generally that means that somebody already has it and I just have not found it yet.

Comment: Based on your comment above, I'm voting to close: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** ...Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called the Decorator Pattern. It's a technique for dynamically adding/modifying behavior:

- http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator
- http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html

To do this, you want to implement the abstract class `Stream`, with a constructor of factory that accepts another `Stream` instance. You provide an implementation for every method/overload of the abstract class that invokes the same method/overload on the decorated `Stream`, plus doing whatever additional work your needs require.

Once you've done that and decorated a `Stream` with your new decorator, It can be used interchangeably by anything else that accepts a `Stream`, including other similar decorators: decorators can even be nested, like layers of an onion to *compose* the behaviors you need.

Something like this:

```
class StreamInterceptor : Stream
{

  public Stream DecoratedInstance { get; set; }

  public event Action<byte[]> BytesRead;
  public event Action<byte[]> BytesWritten;

  public StreamInterceptor( Stream instance )
  {
    if ( instance == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
    this.DecoratedInstance = instance ;
    return ;
  }

  public override bool CanRead
  {
    get { return DecoratedInstance.CanRead; }
  }

  public override bool CanSeek
  {
    get { return DecoratedInstance.CanSeek; }
  }

  public override bool CanWrite
  {
    get { return DecoratedInstance.CanWrite; }
  }

  public override void Flush()
  {
    DecoratedInstance.Flush();
    return;
  }

  public override long Length
  {
    get { return DecoratedInstance.Length; }
  }

  public override long Position
  {
    get { return DecoratedInstance.Position; }
    set { DecoratedInstance.Position = value; }
  }

  public override int Read( byte[] buffer , int offset , int count )
  {
    int bytesRead = DecoratedInstance.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    // raise the bytes read event
    byte[] temp = new byte[bytesRead];
    Array.Copy(buffer,offset,temp,0,bytesRead);
    BytesRead(temp);

    return bytesRead;
  }

  public override long Seek( long offset , SeekOrigin origin )
  {
    return DecoratedInstance.Seek(offset, origin);
  }

  public override void SetLength( long value )
  {
    DecoratedInstance.SetLength(value);
    return;
  }

  public override void Write( byte[] buffer , int offset , int count )
  {

    // raise the bytes written event
    byte[] temp = new byte[count];
    Array.Copy(buffer,offset,temp,0,count);
    BytesWritten(temp);

    DecoratedInstance.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    return;
  }

}
```

Once you have that, you can say something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
  StreamInterceptor si = new StreamInterceptor(File.Open("foo.bar.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.Read));

  si.BytesRead    += (bytes) => { Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes read", bytes.Length); } ;
  si.BytesWritten += (bytes) => { Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes written", bytes.Length); } ;

  Stream s = (Stream) si ;
  DoSomethingUseful(s);

}
```

And your event handler will be invoked whenever somebody reads or writes from the stream.